# Zscore Normalize column in Dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a dataframe representing customers orders with many columns, two of those being 'user_id' and 'dollar'.

for example :

```
    user_id   dollar 
0  1  0.34592  5
1  1  0.02857  7
2  1  0.26672  6
3  1  0.34592  5
4  1  0.02857  9
5  1  0.26672  10
6  1  0.34592  6
      [...]
7  40  0.02857  20
8  40  0.26672  19
9  40  0.34592  8
10 40  0.02857  18
11 40  0.26672  26
```

I want to normalize the value of dollar with respect to the other values in each users row. I want the following result for the previous example:

```
 user_id   dollar norm_dollar
0  1  0.34592  5  -1.02774024
1  1  0.02857  7  0.07905694
2  1  0.26672  6  -0.47434165
3  1  0.34592  5  -1.02774024
4  1  0.02857  9  1.18585412
5  1  0.26672  10  1.73925271
6  1  0.34592  6  -0.47434165
      [...]
7  40  0.02857  20  0.7787612
8  40  0.26672  19  0.57109154
9  40  0.34592  8   -1.71327463
10 40  0.02857  18  0.36342189
```

EDIT:

I would like each results to be normalized wrt each user individually and not the values of the whole column, so for example  with user2,[20,19,8,18] should be normalized as if the mean is the mean of user2 orders, here for example the mean is 16,25 and not the mean of the whole dataframe column.

I know how to do it with one user:

```
user1 = data.loc[data['user_id']==1]
data.loc[data['user_id']==1]['norm_dollar'] = sp.stats.mstats.zscore(user1['dollar'])
```

I tried to do it this way for all the users:

```
data.dollar.div(sp.stats.mstats.zscore(data.groupby('user_id').dollar))
```

But I got an error, do you have any idea on how to proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ways to do this—like joining the `groupby` dataframe back to the original—but I'm starting to like the use of `transform` for stuff like this.

The syntax is still verbose, but I think it's more readable than the join method.

```
df['norm_dollar'] = (df['dollar']
                        - df.groupby('user_id')['dollar'].transform(np.mean)) \
                        / df.groupby('user_id')['dollar'].transform(np.std)
```

If you need to specify degrees of freedom on `np.std`, you can turn that into

```
lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=n)
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work for you:

```
def apply_zscores(x):
    x['norm_dollar'] = zscore(x['dollar'])
    return x

df = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: apply_zscores(x))
```